# Creating a notification at a specific time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a calendar app that I'm working on, and I need to alert the user to an Upcoming event.

so I want to know what's the best practice to do this, and how should I do it, since the current solution I have isn't even working very well.

the way I do it now is by using an AlarmManager to trigger the a BroadcasReciever that creates and shows the notification.

do I need to use a service? and if so, how should I do it?

**CODE:**

```
    private void StartDBUpdateAlarm() // Start the alarm manager for event reminder 
    {
        // Get the eventos orded by date (Later than DateTime.Now),
        // so that we can get the earliest events
        var eventos = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.OrderByDate, DateTime.Now);

        if ((eventos.Count > 0)) // Only create notification if there is an event
        {
            // Create the Intent to pass some info through it to the notification
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReminderReciever));

            // Putting the information that will be passed with constant Id's  
            alarmIntent.PutExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_TITLE, GetString(Resource.String.main_notification_title));
            alarmIntent.PutExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_INFO, "Info");
            alarmIntent.PutExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_CONTENT, eventos[0].Descricao);

            // Creating/Recreating the Pending Intent that will pass the actual information to the notification
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, GerirUtils.NOTIFICATION_REMINDER_ID, alarmIntent, 0);

            // Getting the date and time of the next event, then calculate the diference between DateTime.Now,
            // to know how much time it'll be until next event, so that we know when to trigger the notification
            DateTime eventDateTime = CalendarHelper.EventDateTime(eventos[0]);                
            TimeSpan eventMillis = (eventDateTime - GerirUtils.BaseUTCDate); // BaseDate is just the Utc date = 1970/01/01, because the alarm counts millis since then

            // Creating and setting the alarm manager
            alarm = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, (long)eventMillis.TotalMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

**BROADCAST RECIEVER CLASS**

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class ReminderReciever : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private string type, title, info, content;
    private IList<string> events;
    private int notificationId;
    private Context context;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        this.context = context;
        notificationId = intent.GetIntExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_ID, -1);
        type           = intent.GetStringExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_TYPE);
        events         = intent.GetStringArrayListExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_EVENTS);

        title    = intent.GetStringExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_TITLE);
        info     = intent.GetStringExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_INFO);
        content  = intent.GetStringExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_CONTENT);


        if(notificationId > -1)
            if(type == GerirUtils.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_EVENT_REMINDER)
                ShowNotification();
            else if(type == GerirUtils.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ADDED_EVENTS)
                ShowNotificationList();
    }

    private void ShowNotification() 
    {
        Android.Net.Uri sound = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default", title, NotificationImportance.Default) { Description = content };
            mNotificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_calendario_gerir) // notification icon
                    .SetContentTitle(title)  // title for notification
                    .SetContentText(content) // message for notification
                    .SetContentInfo(info)    // Info message next to content
                    .SetSound(sound)         // set alarm sound for notification
                    .SetAutoCancel(true);    // clear notification after click

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        mBuilder.SetContentIntent(pi);
        mNotificationManager.Notify(0, mBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I managed to find the problem after carefully inspecting the code, it looked like I wasn't sending an notificationId, through the intent. the the intent on the BroadcastReviever was always the default -1, so the if statement was always false and, dumb ol' me, didn't put a message warning when the Id was -1, so I had a harder time to find the error then what I would've if I had the message.

and so, the solution was adding this line of code to the program:

```
private void StartDBUpdateAlarm() // Start the alarm manager for event reminder 
{
    ...
    ...

    if ((eventos.Count > 0)) // Only create notification if there is an event
    {
        // Create the Intent to pass some info through it to the notification
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReminderReciever));

        // MISSING LINE OF CODE
        alarmIntent.PutExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_ID, GerirUtils.NOTIFICATION_REMINDER_ID);
        ...
        ...
        ...            
    }
}
```